# Drupal 7: How to theme nodes based on region?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

How do I control the output of a node rendered inside a specific region?

Inside `Sidebar First`, I can theme *blocks* by creating a `block--sidebar-first.tpl.php` template file. However, creating a `node--sidebar-first.tpl.php` does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Drupal doesn't have support to have node template based on region. You can check out [this link](https://drupal.org/node/1089656#node-suggestion).

If you want to achieve your goal you can use [Display Suite module](https://drupal.org/project/ds). [Here](https://drupal.org/node/644706) are some screen-casts about how to control your content with Display Suite. Here's also a [comment](https://drupal.org/node/2025859#comment-7568181) about this.

Answer (score 0):

For theming a `node` first thing you need a `custom node template` file.

Inorder to do that copy your `node.tpl.php` and rename it as `node-[ur_node_name].tpl.php` .

Now you have created a custom node template. In case of blog entry my node name would be `node-blog.tpl.php` [Drupal-6] and it would be `node--blog.tpl.php` [Drupal-7].

**NOTE:**

Make sure the `[ur_node_name]` part is the `machine readable name`.Now in your new `node template` give your corresponding styles and print the contents of the node.This is how you theme a `node`.Hope this helps you... :)

Comment: The question is: How to theme a node *based on region*.

In other words: How to specify a node template to use for all nodes inside a specific region?